If I Trace "Pickup", will I pickup?
If I had like a Gardevoir with Trace, and finish a battle having traced Pickup while not carrying anything, will it be like my Gardevoir had Pickup so she might pick up something?
Does it change based on the Generation? Or does it never work?

It definitely depends on your Gen, Pickup has changed in 3rd, 5th and 9th. But what do you mean with finish a battle and pick up something? Like outside of the battle? Because a traced ability will only work in-battle.

@pinckerman - Yeah. "Would my Gardevoir act like basically a Pickup Zigzagoon if it traced Pickup?". Well, if you're right, then that'd be the answer. "wouldn't work"

No, as a traced ability will only work in-battle. This means that, when the battle is completed, your Gardevoir will revert to Trace.
This is confirmed also on Serebii forum:

Is it possible to get Pickup-items after a battle if a pokémon have Trace as Ability?


It won't work because once you exit the battle your ability will be reset to Trace

And on PokemonDB:

Trace does not make the Pokemon pickup an item after battle.

